# How to scale a group to exact centimeter dimensions

Tags: adobe-illustrator, scale, dimensions

I have a group of objects and I want to scale them to exact width and height by entering centimeter numbers, not dragging using scale tool.
How can I to that?

Comment: You type the value in the control bar. Or perhaps in the transform dialog if you have control bar disabled.

Comment: Lots of info in the manual about this. Like [here about transforming](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/transforming-objects.html) and [here about scaling](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/scaling-shearing-distorting-objects.html).